# How to add a non-bound column to a DevExpress DB QuantumGrid

Tags: delphi, devexpress, delphi-xe2, vcl, unidac

I am using these components:

```
UniDac for connection to mysql database
DevExpress for QuantumGrid
```

IDE:

```
Embarcadero Rad Studio XE2
```

I have a cxGrid component with one level and a cxGrid1DBTableView specified as the level's View. I can get data from my database and edit it in the grid.  I want to add a column that is not in the bound DataSet.  When I specify the **Column properties** value as **CheckBox** I can see the column but I can't change the value from unchecked to checked by clicking it. The field doesn't have a **DataBinding** assigned to it.  I tried other types of Properties but all are the same I cant change the row value in the grid.

I've been searching for a way to fix this for couple of days, so im hoping you guys can help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you trying to add a checkbox item that does not have a database field behind it?  I have this on one of my forms.

In addition to setting the Properties to "Checkbox" you need to set the DataBinding -> ValueType to "Boolean".  The DataBinding->FieldName can be left blank.

To access the values or change their defaults you can use the DataController like this:

```
View.DataController.Values[i, CheckBoxFieldIndex] := true;
```

In addition you need to set

```
DataController.DataModeController.SmartRefresh := true;
```

To set that option you will also need a KeyField defined for the Controller (DataController.KeyFieldNames)

Setting the SmartRefresh to true will prevent the grid from trying to get an updated value from the underlying dataset.  You need to prevent the refresh or the value for the non-bound column will be set back to Null.  This comes with some restriction on how you update your dataset.  Any changes made to the data in code will not be reflected by the grid unless you explicitly refresh the grid.

Comment: Hmm that helped now i can check it but i cant select multiple rows if i check one row and then try to check the other one the first one unchecks :/ can i do this for multiselect? i mean i need to allow the user to check multiple rows, and i have another column where it has a database field Status and i want to make so that the user could sellect a value from a ComboBox i putted the ComboBox in the options and in the DataBinding the ValueType=String and the FieldName=Status with these settings i can see the checkbox but when i select a different value nothing happens :/

Comment: I forgot about needing to set the "SmartRefresh" property.  I just updated my answer.

Comment: That works great for the CheckBox because it doesnt have a Database field set i will accept your answer :) thankyou could you also explain why can i change the values for the checkbox but i cant for the ComboBox which has a set DataBinding->FieldName = Status and DataBinding->ValueType = String i can see the list but when i select any item it doesnt change in the grid :)

Comment: Not sure on the ComboBox problem.  You should make that into a different question and include more information on how the dataset field and Grid column are setup.

Comment: ok thank you for the help i will make one more question :) you saved me allot of time :)

Answer (score 0):

You also have to fill the field **View.DataController.KeyFieldNames** with one of the datasets fields. At least I need it in Delphi 7.